# Unable to find an entry point named 'GetProcessID' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'

Tags: c#, api, process, handle

Hi im trying to get a processID out of a process handle using the WINAPI 'GetProcessID' but i am getting the following error...

Unable to find an entry point named 'GetProcessID' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.

Checking MSDN i cant see where i have gone wrong..

Comment: What is the P/Invoke code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case matters sometimes, and in particular, it matters in the Windows APIs. Are you refering to the API function *GetProcessId* here (lower-case last letter *d*)?

Answer (score 1):

Your interop code should look like this:

```
[DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetProcessId")]
public static extern  uint GetProcessId([In] System.IntPtr process);
```